# Threading in different methods with Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a class which has several methods and I want to call each of those methods in a different thread.

```
class Base : public QThread
{
    copy();
    move();
    remove();
    etc();
    ....    
    ....
    run();
}
```

Is this possible or should I inherit different classes which implement the functionality in their run() method? ( which would lead to several derived classes )

Thank you.

Comment: different threads as in different objects of base class or some other threads altogether ?

Comment: Are you trying to make sure the methods are thread-safe (can be called from multiple threads) or are you trying to make an object that itself spawns multiple threads, each of which calls a method on the object?

Comment: The second one, the object wants to run different methods on different situations, but each of them should have it's own thread

Comment: Each thread would do it's own job, however these methods are in one family and they should pack in one package, thus I thought that is a better approach to have them all in one class rather to derive multiple classes for each situation

Comment: fyi, according to Qt Devs... "You're Doing it Wrong"... they even admit to it on their blog that the documentation is incorrect and out-dated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please  http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible or should I inherit different classes which implement the functionality in
>   their `run()` method? ( which would lead to several derived classes )

That depends on whether you want those methods to execute concurrently (on a thread pool, or on dedicated threads), or serialized.

1. If serialized:

   Use the [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). Another word for that is [Active Object](http://herbsutter.com/2010/09/24/effective-concurrency-know-when-to-use-an-active-object-instead-of-a-mutex/). Neither C++ nor Qt support Actors out of the box, so you have to take it as a pattern. This should get you started:

   ```
   class Base : public QObject {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       explicit Base( QObject * parent=0 )
           : QObject( parent ),
             thread(),
             queue(),
             mutex(),
             queueNotEmpty()
       {
           thead.start();
       }
       ~Base() {
           // shut down thread:
           enqueue( 0 ); // end marker
           thread.wait(); // join with worker thread
       }
   public Q_SLOTS:
       void copy( const QString & from, const QString & to ) {
           enqueue( new CopyCommand( from, to ) );
       }
       void move( const QString & from, const QString & to ) {
           enqueue( new MoveCommand( from, to ) );
       }

   private:
       struct Command {
           virtual ~Command() {}
           virtual void exec() = 0;
       }
       class CopyCommand : public Command {
           const QString from, to;
           CopyCommand( const QString & from, const QString & to )
               : Command(), from( from ), to( to ) {} 
           void exec() { QFile::copy( from, to ); }
       };
       class MoveCommand : public Command {
           // ...
       };
       // ...
   private:
       void enqueue( Command * cmd ) {
           const QMutexLocker locker( &mutex );
           queue.enqueue( cmd );
           queueNotEmpty.wakeOne();
       }

       /* reimpl */ void run() {
           while ( true ) {
               QMutexLocker locker( &mutex );
               while ( queue.isEmpty() )
                   queueNotEmpty.wait( &mutex );
               Command * cmd = queue.dequeue();
               locker.unlock():
               if ( !cmd ) return; // end marker
               cmd->exec();
               delete cmd;
           }
       }
   private:
       QThread thread;
       QQueue<Command*> queue;
       QMutex mutex; // protects 'queue'
       QWaitCondition queueNotEmpty;
   };
   ```
2. If concurrent:

   1. If on a thread pool:

      Use `QThreadPool`/`QRunnable`. Same code as above, but replace the `QThread`/`QMutex`/`QQueue`/`QWaitCondition` quartet with `QThreadPool`, `Command` with `QRunnable`, and `Base::enqueue()` with `QThreadPool::start()`.

      When using a thread pool, remember that you [shouldn't put (potentially) blocking operations on `QThreadPool::globalInstance()`](http://herbsutter.com/2009/04/20/effective-concurrency-use-thread-pools-correctly-keep-tasks-short-and-nonblocking/) (so create a local `QThreadPool` if the operations, like in my example, are (potentially) blocking).
   2. If using dedicated threads:

      Don't inherit `Base` from `QThread`, but make every `Base` function create and start its own `MoveCommand` etc, deriving from `QThread`, and reimplementing `run()`. The `finished()` signal of these `QThread`s should be connected to their `deleteLater()` slots as a way to ensure cleanup.

      While this is probably closest to what you wanted originally, you really don't want to use one thread for each file operation (assuming they're file operations), since they're relatively expensive to create. Even if the stuff is CPU-bound, using dedicated threads can easily result in over-committing the CPUs, and everything runs slower than before.

Comment: Thank you for your brief answer, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, QThread::run() is only a method to start a new thread. Just call the methods from different threads, and they will be executed there.

As of design: inter-thread communication is frequently built around the message-passing model, and Qt's queued connection mode makes it simple to implement: you just make your methods to be slots, and in run() you just start a QMessageLoop via the exec() method:

```
class Base : public QThread
{
public slots:
    void copy();
    void move();
    void remove();
    void etc();

...

protected:
    void run()
    {
        exec();
    }
}
```

Now you can call your methods via signals, and each instance of Base will execute them in its own thread.

Comment: _Now you can call your methods via signals, and each instance of Base will execute them in its own thread._ Did you actually try?

Comment: @mmutz: I've built some userspace 'drivers' for Linux using this technique :) I might have forgotten to mention some details (as it was some years ago), but the whole thing worked just as described :)

Comment: Actually, the detail I've really forgotten is whether we have to move the object to our thread with QObject::moveToThread(), or not (more likely the former, but I'm not sure).

Comment: yes, that's the missing piece of information to make it work for _ordinary_ `QObject`s. However, this `QObject` is-a `QThread`. `moveToThead(this)` _could_ work (_outside_ of `run()`), but at the very least you have to remember the thread in which the `Base` instance was created, and call `moveToThread(old thread)` from the end of `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

As for addition to vines's answer. You could issue those slots not only via signals. You could also use the following code:

```
Base *pBase = new Base;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pBase, "copy");
```

If the `copy` method should accept arguments, use `Q_ARG` macros to pass them. The assistant has some good examples (search for `invokeMethod()`).
One more thing, if you don't want do declare those methods as slots, but still need it to be invokable by the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`, you could prepend it with the `Q_INVOKABLE` macros.

```
...
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void copy();
...
```