# Monitor Qt GUI from QThread class

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am trying to run a background thread (qthread) that needs to monitor a checkbox in the gui and it will not run!  It builds but during runtime i get this error:

"Unhandled exception at 0x0120f494 in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdce55."

and it breaks on the "connect" line.  What is the best way to do this?

```
guiclass::guiclass(){
    thread *t = new thread();
}

thread::thread(){
     guiclass *c = new guiclass();
     connect(c->checkBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checked(int)));

     ....
     start work
     ....
}

bool thread::checked(int c){
     return(c==0);
}

void thread::run(){

    if(checked()){
        do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you initializing `c->checkBox`? how are you dealing with the fact that `new guiclass` calls `new thread` calls `new guiclass` calls `new thread` calls `new guiclass`calls `new thread` calls `new guiclass` ...

Comment: Clearly I am not dealing with the threads calling each other, looks like my problem.  So, how would i monitor the guiclass without creating a guiclass object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event queue of any `QThread` object is actually handled by the thread that started it, which is quite unintuitive.  The common solution is to create a "handler" object (derived from `QObject`), associate it with your worker thread by calling `moveToThread`, and then bind the checkbox signal to a slot of this object.

The code looks something like this:

```
class ObjectThatMonitorsCheckbox : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
     // ...

public slots:
     void checkboxChecked(int checked);
}
```

In the code that creates the thread:

```
QThread myWorkerThread;

ObjectThatMonitorsCheckbox myHandlerObject;

myHandlerObject.moveToThread(&myworkerThread);
connect(c->checkBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), &myHandlerObject, 
    SLOT(checkboxChecked(int)));

myWorkerThread.start();
```

One key point: Don't subclass `QThread` -- all the actual work is done in your handler object.

Hope this helps!

See also: [Qt: Correct way to post events to a QThread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208339/qt-correct-way-to-post-events-to-a-qthread)