# Thread Affinity: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qthread, worker, qobject, affinity

I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572432/qt-multithreaded-email-qobject-cannot-create-children-for-a-parent-that-is-in), but I feel that I am implementing the correct pattern and still I can't get it done!

Well, I have a `Gui` to start and stop data acquisition from a `serial port` and display necessary communication messages. To keep the `Gui` responsive, I move the *worker* to a thread. I tried to implement *thread affinity*, according to: [How to Use QThread in the Right Way](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-2/) and [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). When I click on start button, I receive;

```
QWinEventNotifier: event notifiers cannot be enabled from another thread
QWinEventNotifier: event notifiers cannot be enabled from another thread
QWinEventNotifier: event notifiers cannot be enabled from another thread
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0x142cd390), parent's thread is QThread(0x1259b070), current thread is QThread(0x142db1f0)
```

What am I missing? Here is a part of the code related to my question:

**Worker header**

```
#ifndef COMPORT_H
#define COMPORT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSerialPort>

class QTimer;

class ComPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ComPort(const QString &portName, QObject* parent = 0);
    ~ComPort();

private:
    QSerialPort*    port;
    QString         portMsg;
    QByteArray      responseData;
signals:
    void finished();

private slots:
    void onReadyRead();
    void setupPort();

};

#endif // COMPORT_H
```

**Worker cpp**

```
#include "comport.h"

ComPort::ComPort(const QString &portName, QObject *parent)
    :QObject(parent)
{
    this->port = new QSerialPort(portName);
}

ComPort::~ComPort()
{
    port->close();
    delete port;
}

void ComPort::setupPort()
{
    port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud19200);
    port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);

    connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));

    *SOME CODE HERE*
}

void ComPort::onReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray bytes = port->readAll() ;
    qDebug() << "bytes:" << bytes <<"\n";
    responseData.append(bytes);
}
```

and **Gui**

```
#include "gui.h"
#include "ui_gui.h"

gui::gui(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::gui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnstartButtonClicked()));
}

gui::~gui()
{
    delete ui;
}

void gui::OnstartButtonClicked()
{
    QThread*  cThread = new QThread;
    ComPort*  cPort   = new ComPort(QString("COM4"));
    cPort->moveToThread(cThread);
    connect(cPort, SIGNAL(finished()), cThread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(cPort, SIGNAL(finished()), cPort, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(cThread, SIGNAL(finished()), cThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(cThread, SIGNAL(started()), cPort, SLOT(setupPort()));
    cThread->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the answer from [Kim Bowles Sørhus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910541/4058363), I solved my problem. I was creating a serial port in the constructor of `ComPort` that is called in the main thread. When the `cPort` object is moved to the `cThread` the `QSerialPort` still has its thread affinity set to the original thread. A solution is to create the `QSerialPort` in `ComPort::setupPort`.