# The thread persists when called again after a new thread invokes the start function in QT

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have an issue as follows: when I create and start Thread 1, and then create and start Thread 2, I observe that Thread 1 is being run again, and the data is getting mixed up. I am unsure about the cause and how to fix it.
Below is my code:

Worker.cpp

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void request_server(const QString& str_url, const qint64 &key_tag); {
        qint64 key_tag;
        qDebug() << "Worker ::request_server: " << QThread::currentThread() << ",id thread: " <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << ",key_tag: " << key_tag;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result, QThread::currentThread());
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(qint64 result, QThread *thread_req);
};
```

Controller.cpp

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    Controller() {
        
    }

    void request() {
        qint64 tag_req = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
        QString str_url = "http:abc.xyz";

        Worker *worker = new Worker();
        QThread *workerThread = new QThread();
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::request_server);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
        
        emit operate(str_url, tag_req);
        qDebug()<<"Controller::request"<<tag_req;
    }

public slots:
    void handleResults(const qint64& tag, QThread* thread_req) {
         qDebug() << "Controller::updateResults" << tag << thread_req->currentThread() << thread_req->currentThreadId();

    }
signals:
    void operate(const QString &url, const qint64 &key_tag);
};
```

When I use a QTimer to periodically call the request function, the thread doesn't run as expected. Below is the log when running:

```
Controller ::request  1709110337385
Controller ::request  1709110337401
Controller ::request  1709110337417
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad3c28e670) ,id thread:  0x27dc ,key_tag:  1709110337385
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad3c28e670) ,id thread:  0x27dc ,key_tag:  1709110337401
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad3c28e670) ,id thread:  0x27dc ,key_tag:  1709110337417
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad3c28e910) ,id thread:  0x118c ,key_tag:  1709110337401
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad3c28e910) ,id thread:  0x118c ,key_tag:  1709110337417
 Worker ::request_server:  QThread(0x2ad42ee7a10) ,id thread:  0x40b8 ,key_tag:  1709110337417
Controller ::updateResults 16044279834542133 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
Controller ::updateResults 16044279834542133 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
Controller ::updateResults 257 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
Controller ::updateResults 216 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
Controller ::updateResults 216 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
Controller ::updateResults 216 QThread(0x2ad2a190050) 0x4114
thread_req is finished
```

Comment: `Worker::request_server` is never called in the code shown.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `emit operate()` will emit the `operate()` signal, which will result in `doWork()` being called on all the slots that signal is connected to, including the older QThread object (if that object is still in existence).  If you want your `operate()` signal to only result in a slot-method being called inside the newest thread, you should probably call `disconnect()` on the old QThread object sometime beforehand to ensure that it won't receive any further operate-signals in the future.

Comment: @G.M. sorry. i update source

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Should I disconnect immediately after `emit operate()`? because I make function calls many times and in a short time

Comment: @KaiAkiho yeah, maybe you're better off calling something like `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` to schedule the `request_server()` slot-method-call, instead of making a signal->slot connection.  Something like what is specified here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948634/131930