# Updating GUI from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I need to have a computationally intensive function run in a different thread so that the GUI doesn't freeze or turn grey when it's running.

I followed this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501374/2904614

But the GUI still freezes and turns grey.

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->textBrowser->setFont(QFont("Monospace",11));
    ui->textBrowser->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);

    updater->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(updater,SIGNAL(req()), this, SLOT(getCheckSum()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(destroyed()), updater, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

When the user clicks the designated button. Since there may be a lot of files in one directory, the GUI will freeze as QDirIterator goes through all of them. I'm hoping to add a progress bar, that will show the user the program is still functioning.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    updater->getHash();
    //getCheckSum();
}
```

**EDIT**
I would like to have the function `MainWindow::getCheckSum()` run in a different thread than the GUI. How will I implement this?

Github: https://github.com/Jyang772/PenguSniff

Comment: Where do you new updater? Does it have a parent? Do you start the thread?

Comment: I do that in the class declaration for MainWindow. Yes, I start the thread after connecting the slots/signals. updater doesn't have a parent, since I can't use `moveToThread` if it does.

Comment: Where your for loop is executed? It is unclear from you question and probably runs in GUI thread. I propose to put it in getHash() before emit req().

Comment: @Basilevs I did put it in `getHash()`. Right now I just replaced it with an infinite while loop to test if GUI is responsive.

Comment: @MicroPenguin, please update the question in a way, that it would become clear where loop is executed. It is still unclear what is "the function I want to call in a different thread". Also, take a look at [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you only need to run one function i would recommend QtConcurrent. Extract form the docs:

***Running a Function in a Separate Thread***

To run a function in another thread, use QtConcurrent::run():

```
extern void aFunction();
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(aFunction);
```

This will run aFunction in a separate thread obtained from the default QThreadPool. You can use the QFuture and QFutureWatcher classes to monitor the status of the function.

Comment: By the way, there is no other framework having as cool classes as QFuture and QFutureWatcher. Sounds like easy implementation of a time machine

Comment: Thanks! However, I have some other functions that I would like to call if the user presses different buttons. I need to clear the textbrowser of any text, however it seems as though the thread starts before the textbrowser clears itself.

Comment: Clearing a text browser is not intended to be run in separated thread. As by your description only the computing-function has to be run in a separate thread, therefor using QtConcurrent is eligible.

Comment: I realized that I had a global variable with the same name as a local variable in the function. This was why textbrowser was never being modified when I wanted it to. Thank you for suggesting `QtConcurrent`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the function of a class in another thread directly:

```
updater->getHash();
```

It causes undefined behavior in your application and makes it crash. The correct way is to emit a signal from your MainWindow which is connected to the getHash() slot in updater:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(getHash()), updater, SLOT(getHash()));


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit getHash();
}
```

This will result in a queued connection and runs the slot in the updater thread.

Comment: The application doesn't 'crash', it just turns grey when iterating through directories. When it's done, the GUI becomes responsive again. I tried this method, and still the same result. How do I know for sure it's being processed on a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

You call your getHash() computational function (it is computational as per your comment) in GUI thread. Bind it to clicked signal, then it will be invoked in object's thread.

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(getHash()));
```