# Launching a while-loop freezes program even if using another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

In my (Qt-)program I need a continuous request of a value which I get from an external source. But I did not want that this request freezes the whole program, so I created a separate thread for this function. But even if it is running in a separate thread, the GUI freezes, too. Why?

Code for the request function:

```
void DPC::run()
{
    int counts = 0, old_counts = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(50000);
        counts = Read_DPC();
        if(counts != old_counts)
        {
            emit currentCount(counts);
            old_counts = counts;
        }

    }
}
```

`Read_DPC()` returns an int value I want to sent to a lineEdit in my GUI.
The main class looks like

```
class DPC: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void run();
signals:
    void currentCount(int);
};
```

This code is called in the main function as:

```
DPC *newDPC = new DPC;
connect(newDPC, SIGNAL(currentCount(int)), SLOT(oncurrentCount(int)));
connect(newDPC, SIGNAL(finished()), newDPC, SLOT(deleteLater()));
newDPC->run();
```

How can I prevent this code from freezing my GUI? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you launching a separate thread?

Comment: I thought via creating a subclass which is derived from QThread? According to some threads (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545961/modify-qt-gui-from-background-worker-thread) or (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501284/qt-updating-main-window-with-second-thread)

Comment: Why do you call `run` from the main thread? Didn't you want some other thread to call `run`? Wasn't that the whole point of deriving from QThread?

Comment: How should I start the subthread if not using `run`? I tried using `start`, but that did not work, too (I simply replaced `run` with `start`, if that was correct)

Comment: @arc_lupus One bug at a time. Fix the call to `run` and then re-test, describing in as much detail as possible what goes wrong after that bug is fixed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Thanks for the comment, but my problem is already solved...

Comment: This is probably one of the reasons why `QThread::run` is protected. You should make it a protected member as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you code run in GUI thread because you use `run()` method to start thread, so try to call `start()` as documentation and many examples said.

Try:

```
DPC *newDPC = new DPC;
connect(newDPC, SIGNAL(currentCount(int)), SLOT(oncurrentCount(int)));
connect(newDPC, SIGNAL(finished()), newDPC, SLOT(deleteLater()));
newDPC->start();//not run
```

Anyways you can call `thread()` method or [currentThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#currentThread) to see in which thread some objects live.

Comment: Using `start()` leads to freeze, too.

Comment: @arc_lupus add qDebug() << thread() to your mainWindow and in the run() Did you get same threads? What exactly you get? Same threads means same adress in the output

Comment: @arc_lupus I run same code right now and try to undestand problem. Tell me please what you can see when in run you'll wrote(in while loop): `qDebug()  << thread() << currentThread();`

Comment: @arc_lupus when I use run instead of start my GUI freeze too, call run is wrong, now I try understand why start() do not work for you.

Comment: @arc_lupus and also try `qDebug() << currentThread() <<"constructor";` in thread constructor.

Comment: @arc_lupus currentThread() you should use in QThread subclass because it is a static method of QThread

Comment: just assumption, will you have the same freezing if you will comment out usleep(50000); ?

Comment: @Chernobyl: Output in main thread is: QThread(0x76aad0) QThread(0x76aad0), in sub thread I get QThread(0x1f80ad0) DPC(0x21aa2d0)

Comment: @N1ghtLight no, I just get more then 271374 prints, because while(1) is very fast :)

Comment: @Chernobyl, I though that usleep is unix native method, but it looks like here it's QThread's method

Comment: @Chernobyl: Freeze is gone if I remove the usleep(), but I get no update of the lineEdit()

Comment: @arc_lupus Something strange. I'm on Windows and usleep works normal for me, maybe try to use msleep? Set interval in milliseconds.

Comment: @Chernobyl: That works, too, but I still get no signal

Comment: @arc_lupus Please clarify, you GUI now not freeze and your thread works normal(print something every time to see that all good)but you can't catch signal, then try to print something in slot too(to know is slot was called at all). And post code of slot

Comment: @Chernobyl: Problem solved, my read_DPC() function simply does not return anything-> nothing to display...

Comment: @arc_lupus Ok, we do this :)

Comment: @N1ghtLight I will, it was cool.There is no any result from voting up comment, but your contribution will not be forgotten or omitted ;)