# Simple digital clock by using Qt and QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I want to create a program by using Qt framework. The aim is to write a program which uses QThread to show a simple digital clock. but nothing happened when running.

This is the subclass of Qthread for running

paytamtimers.h

```
#ifndef PAYTAMTIMERS_H
#define PAYTAMTIMERS_H
#include <QThread>

class PaytamTimers:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PaytamTimers();
QString now;
protected:
    virtual void run();
private:
    QMutex mutex;
    QThread *thread;

signals:
    void mySignal(QString);
};

#endif // PAYTAMTIMERS_H
```

and this is the implementation of this.class
paytamtimers.cpp

```
#include "paytamtimers.h"
#include <QTime>

PaytamTimers::PaytamTimers()
{
    this->now="";
    this->thread=new QThread(0);
}

void PaytamTimers::run(){
forever{
    mutex.lock();
    this->now=QTime::currentTime().toString();
    this->thread->sleep(1000);
    emit mySignal(this->now);
    mutex.unlock();

}
}
```

and this is the implementation of GUI form. This for consist of QLabel and an instance of paytamtimers,just for simplity

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "paytamtimers.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    t=new PaytamTimers();
    t->start();
    connect(t,SIGNAL(t->mySignal(QString)),this,SLOT(this->now(const QString &string)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::now(const QString &string){
    this->ui->label->setText(t->now);
}
```

Comment: Look at this example:http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/countDownClockwithQTimer.php#.UijZWMaMm8M

Comment: Also, follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please for the correct way to use QThread. Subclassing from QThread just to implement a worker is not the correct way to use threads

Comment: [Something you might want to read](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not hold the mutex while sleeping in the thread. In fact, your mutex is completely unnecessary.
2. Your `connect` statement is wrong, as noted by [hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde). The `this` parameter is implied, so you could simply say:

   ```
   connect(t, SIGNAL(mySignal(QString)), SLOT(now(QString)));
   ```
3. You don't need to use a thread in order to emit periodic time updates.

Your `MainWindow` could look like below. It'll take care to fire the timer event as close to full second as possible.

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QBasicTimer m_timer;
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) {
            QTime t = QTime::currentTime();
            m_timer.start(1000 - t.msec(), this);
            // round to nearest second
            if (t.msec() < 500) t = t.addMsecs(-t.msec()); else t = t.addMSecs(1000-t.msec());
            now(t.toString());
        }
    }
    void now(const QString &);
    ...
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        m_timer.start(1000 - QTime::currentTime().msec(), this);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connect statement is wrong, it should be:

```
connect(t, SIGNAL(mySignal(QString)), this, SLOT(now(QString)));
```

To catch problems like this, first of all check console output, there you should see a warning about failing connect. And another thing, use Qt Creator autocompletion to fill in `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, because it is very easy to make stupid mistakes, which will not be spotted by compiler.

There are a few other funny things, such as the seemingly useless extra `QThread*` member variable in your `QThread` subclass, and an unnecessary mutex, but these shouldn't stop things from working.

In general, it seems you're just learning Qt. I'd leave threads for later, they have a lot of small gotchas and details, and worrying about them while also learning the Qt basics will not make life easy.