# PyQt : Emtting signal from QThread to QWidget

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I've been meaning to implement a chat client/server, with PyQt handling the GUI front. The problem I'm facing is when I want to tell an already connected client that another new client has joined. Initially I worked it around by adding a "refresh users" button which sends the client the updated list. However, now when a client has to message another, I realise that I will obviously have to create a separate thread which keeps on checking for data from the server. I have trying since yesterday, reading various posts/answers, forums but still can't get this to work.

What I want is a separate thread which is executed at the start of the program that checks for data from the server and can emit signals that instigate the function in a GUI thread to change the users list. How do I make a thread that works constantly and emits signals that can be caught by the main GUI loop ? And how should I catch the signal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as with other Qt components: you create a QThread for your network management, the QThread derived class emits signals with some data coming from network; on the main thread side, you have QObjects and QWidgets that you connect to those signals. Take a look at the following (in that order):

- [Qt Threading Basics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html)
- [Thread Support in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads.html)
- [How to use QThreads](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)
- Another [How to use QThreads](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/)
- [what is the correct way to implement a QThread... (example please...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please)

Once you have read these and tried your own code, then you can post a new question with more specific issues you are having. Otherwise, your question is too broad.