# how to implement QProgressBar for heavy computation?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qprogressbar

I am developing a GUI in QT which performs some heavy computation based on user input . I doing all the computation in a function say **start_computation()** , as start_computation() function is called my GUI hangs since it is busy in executing start_computation() function . So, I want to use QProgressBar to let the user know that the GUI is performing some task in the background .
 what will be the best way to implement QProgressBar in such case ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952474/non-blocking-worker-interrupt-file-copy?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the whole complex computation is handled by one function, it can be easily be ported to the [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) framework, doing something like the following, as mentioned in the tutorial linked below:

```
 QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&this->MyObject, &MyClass::LongFunction);
```

A `FutureWatcher` object will then update the progress bar according to the future completion information.

There's a complete example on how to use [QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) with QFutures and [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) in general here: https://wiki.qt.io/Progress_Bar

Adding partial completion information to the progress bar will be trivial, emitting the appropriate information using the `signals/slot` mechanism.

Comment: In the built-in example that is similar to the one on the wiki you linked to they use QtConcurrent::map() and connect the progress bar's setValue and cancel to signals emitted from the QFutureWatcher that aren't available when using QtConcurent::run(). Working from the linked example, would I instead simply add progress update a signal to MyClass that is emitted within LongFunction and connect that signal to the ProgressDialog setValue() in the form? Is it ok if MyClass is MainWindow itself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your exact scenario but if your computation is one function ( `start_computation()`), you can use **thread** and `QThread` is a good solution.

In fact you need to put your heavy-computation in a new thread. Then you can check computation-progress from main(GUI) thread at times and update your progress bar.

**PS:** To see some example of implementing `QThread` in right way, you can refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please) and [Here](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to move your `start_computation()` function out into it's own thread, then using the `signal/slot` mechanism update the GUI correctly. The GUI has to always run on the main thread, and an intensive function will always block that.

There's a good discussion on how to use `QThreads` correctly here: http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/

Comment: I'd say to avoid messing around with `QThreads` when possible. There's a nice concurrent API in Qt provided by QtConcurrent module that can help with this kind of situation. Especially when there's a long-running function that does the heavy work and needs to be executed outside of the GUI thread.

Comment: I always forget about `QtConcurrent` for some reason, but yeah it's probably a lot more appropriate for this.