# How to wait for multiple QWaitConditions

Tags: c++, qt

Under windows I can use WaitForMultipleObjects. Is there a way to do something in QT?
What I want to do is: wait for an event to occur (QWaitCondition) while be able to react for instance to an abort request.

Comment: If you wait for events (including an abort event) it sounds right to communicate using a queue for events which are processed in the thread. Every Qt thread has an event queue to which you can `postEvent`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please

Comment: I understand the concept that QThread allows you to emit a signal, which is processed in a slot running in a different thread. However this is actually not the design pattern I want to use here.

Comment: I don#'t mean signal or slots but `postEvent`. I am assuming that your thread basically is a worker thread that an event, e.g. a work package, processes it and waits for the next event. I would usually implement this with a thread-safe queue, similar to Go's channel, but Qt implements this already.

Comment: Or send your thread command objects over a queue.