# (QT) QThread not executing a second time

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm new to threading and doing an exercise question where I'm writing a program that creates a list of files in a directory and displays it in a `QTableWidget`. It uses a separate thread to do the file finding. I'm not sub-classing from `QThread` due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please) question. When I run the program and search a directory it works fine the first time and displays the names of the files in the table view as expected. But when I try do it again the `QTableView` doesn't update.

While debugging I notice my breakpoints in my `fileFinder` class don't get triggered on the second try. It seems like the thread doesn't run again the second time like it does the first and I can't figure out why. I'm pretty sure it's a simple bug that I'm missing. Any help will be apprecaited. The code:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "filefinder.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void addToTable(QString name);
    void on_btnBrowse_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread workerThread;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //set up tableWidget code here omitted

}

void MainWindow::on_btnBrowse_clicked()
{
    //clear tableWidget contents
    ui->tableFiles->setRowCount(0);

    fileFinder *finder = new fileFinder;
    finder->moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), finder, SLOT(run())); //execute run() function when worker thread has started
    connect(finder, SIGNAL(name(QString)), this, SLOT(addToTable(QString)));    //pass names from thread to handler slot
    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), finder, SLOT(deleteLater()));    //delete thread when done

    //get directory
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Select Directory", "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
    ui->dirEdit->setText(dir);

    //set directory in thread object
    finder->setDir(dir);

    //start worker thread
    workerThread.start();
}

//add each name to tableWidget one at a time
void MainWindow::addToTable(QString name)
{
    QTableWidgetItem *fileName = new QTableWidgetItem(name);
    int row = ui->tableFiles->rowCount();
    ui->tableFiles->insertRow(row);
    ui->tableFiles->setItem(row, 0, fileName);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    delete ui;
}
```

filefinder.h

```
#ifndef FILEFINDER_H
#define FILEFINDER_H

#include <QStringList>
#include <QThread>

class fileFinder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    fileFinder();
    void searchDir();
    void setDir(QString path);

public slots:
    void run();

signals:
    void name(QString n);

private:
    QStringList files;
    QString m_dir;
};

#endif // FILEFINDER_H
```

filefinder.cpp

```
#include "filefinder.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <QDir>

fileFinder::fileFinder()
{

}

//return list of all files in the directory
void fileFinder::searchDir()
{
    QDir dir;
    dir.setPath(m_dir);
    //get list of file names sorted by name
    files = dir.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Name);
}

//set the selected directory
void fileFinder::setDir(QString path)
{
    m_dir = path;
}

//executed when thread is started
void fileFinder::run()
{
    searchDir();

    //iterate through list of files and emit names one by one
    foreach(QString f, files){
        emit(name(f));
        usleep(100);    //pause inbetween emits
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will destroy your thread object after finish

```
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), finder, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

You need to keep your thread as pointer and recreate it before start.

In mainwindow.h

```
QThread* workerThread;
```

And then

```
workerThread = new QThread;
finder->moveToThread(workerThread);

connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), finder, SLOT(run()));
connect(finder, SIGNAL(name(QString)), this, SLOT(addToTable(QString)));
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), finder, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do 2 changes:

- Change the type of workerThread to QThread*
- assign every `btn_Browse_clicked()` a `new QThread()` to workerThread

I'm sorry, I don't know why it works, but it does.
Maybe anybody else knows an answer, i would be interested in.